# doInBackground (Agenda. .. params) does not return bitmap image in listView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-imageview, android-adapter

I'm 3 days ago now looking for an answer and find no satisfying. 
I created a listview to populate it with a picture and a text, the way the image is saved in sqlite database and image is in sd card of the phone, but only that not all rows from the database has a path to image so I'm placing a default image, but the problem is that even the images that are the path, not returning to this image, follows my adapter code below:

```
public class AgendaListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Agenda> {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Agenda> lista;
private Agenda agenda;
int resources;

//constructor
public AgendaListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Agenda> lista){
    super(context, resource, lista);

    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.resources = resource;
    this.lista = lista;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return lista.size();
}

@Override
public Agenda getItem(int position) {
    return lista.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    agenda = lista.get(position);
    //cria uma referencia para viewHolder
    //creates a reference to
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    //verifica se a view esta sendo reusada ou não
    //verifies that the view is being reused or not
    if(convertView == null){
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.linha_listar_telefones, null);
        viewHolder.mNome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nome);
        viewHolder.mImagem = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listar_contato_imagem);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }else{

        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }



    if(agenda != null){
        if(viewHolder.mNome != null){
            viewHolder.mNome.setText(agenda.nome);              
        }

        if(viewHolder.mImagem != null){
            viewHolder.mImagem.setTag(lista.get(position));
            Log.w("Livro", "Positiom: "+position);
                Log.e("Livro", "Viewhol.imagem não é nulo "+viewHolder.mImagem);
                new loadImageTask(viewHolder.mImagem).execute();
        }

    }


    return convertView;
}




private static class ViewHolder{

    protected TextView mNome;
    protected ImageView mImagem;
}
Bitmap b = null;

private class loadImageTask extends AsyncTask<Agenda, Void, Bitmap>{

    private ImageView imv;
    private String path;

    public loadImageTask(ImageView imv) {
        this.imv = imv;
        this.path = agenda.caminho_imagem;
   }



    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Agenda... params) {

        Log.w("Livro", "path: "+path);

        File file = new File( 
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + path);

        if(file.exists()){
            b =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

        }

        return b;

        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if(result != null && imv != null){
            Log.i("Livro", "Result do onPostExcute não é nulo: "+result);
            imv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imv.setImageBitmap(result);
        }else{
            Log.i("Livro", "Result do onPostExcute é nulo: "+result);
            imv.setImageResource(R.drawable.foto_pessoa);
        }
    }


}
```

}

In the logcat path returning this: `content ://media/external/images/media/16`
The variable file is returning the following result: `/ storage/emulated/sdcard0content ://media/external/images/media/16`

I know the result of this wrong file, but would transform into uri path and pass a uri to file?

Thanks guys!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path `//media/external/images/media/16` is a `Media Uri`...You have to get the actual file path from the `Uri` and then set the image to the `ImageView`.

Get the real file path from `Media Uri` as below and the returned path is absolute file path...

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
  Cursor cursor = null;
  try { 
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
  } finally {
    if (cursor != null) {
      cursor.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Get `Bitmap` from the path returned by `getRealPathFromURI()` method as below...

Context mContext;

```
public loadImageTask(Context context, ImageView imv) {

    this.mContext = context;

    this.imv = imv;
    this.path = agenda.caminho_imagem;
}

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Agenda... params) {

    Log.w("Livro", "path: "+path);

    File file = new File(getRealPathFromURI(mContext, path));

    if(file.exists()){
        b =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

    }

    return b;
}
```

And pass the context of the activity through the asynctask constructor as below...

```
new loadImageTask(context, viewHolder.mImagem).execute();
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, the pictures are going to listView, but now for some reason they are only going to the first line.

Comment: find out the cause through debug.